# Extracting info from row content in R

Tags: r, dataframe, metadata, data-manipulation

I come up with a problem that I have not been able to solve working with R. I appreciate the support of the community. Attached an example of my data as shown in my .csv files. I need to create columns (factors) with part of the information specified in the first column (Image name).

So, I need to go from this:

| Image | Class | Num Detections |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S1.tif | Left: fiber tracts | 206 |
| KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S10.tif | left: fiber tracts | 1632 |
|  |  |  |

To this:

| Image | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Class | Num Detections |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S1.tif | M012 | KO25 | MCAO | S1 | Left: fiber tracts | 206 |
| KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S10.tif | M012 | KO25 | MCAO | S10 | Left: fiber tracts | 1632 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Basically, I need to create 4 columns that record/reproduce the information recorded in the image name.

Any idea of how to perform this in R code? I appreciate your help

Comment: Have a search here on Stackoverflow for `[r] str_extract` from the *stringr* package or `[r] strcapture` in base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ans <- cbind(df , do.call(rbind , strsplit(df$Image , "[_\\.]"))[,3:6])
colnames(ans) <- c( colnames(ans[1:3]), paste0("Name" , 1:4))
ans <- cbind(ans[c(-2,-3)] , ans[c(2,3)])
```

- output

```
                             Image Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1  KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S1.tif  M012  KO25  MCAO    S1
2 KLF4_Exp1_M012_KO25_MCAO_S10.tif  M012  KO25  MCAO   S10
              Class Num.Detections
1 Left:fiber_tracts            206
2 left:fiber_tracts           1632
```

Comment: I did the job as you suggested. I appreciate your support